# Uniting 3 Locations Through VPN

Tags: cisco-vpn

Hello and thanks in advance,

My issue is that, at the moment, my company has two locations. We'll call them "A" and "B". I already have them synced using a VPN. We just purchased another building this past month and I need to also sync that location,"C", with A and B. Location A is located abroad and they have to go through a third-party company to install a VPN. My other locations, "B" and "C", are both in the States and I control the Ciscos. I managed to sync location "B" and "C" through a VPN. My problem is that in order to make "C" a domain controller, it needs to communicate with the Master Domain which is located at location "A". I know that simply creating a Triangle of VPN's having "A"->"B","A"->"C", and "B"->"C" would work. But, as I said, in order for me to establish another VPN from "A" to "C" would take a while since I have to reach a third-party. Is it possible, if so then what steps do i need to take, for me to have a system where "C" goes through "B" to reach "A" (I apologize, I know that sounds confusing)? Basically, have location "B" be my middle man between "A" and "C"? Once again, I appreciate your help. Let me know if you need some more collaboration of detail to fully understand what I am asking, I know it wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is routing traffic between 2 different VPN tunnels.

It can be done, and since you say Cisco I'll presume ASA's:

https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/12110341/routing-traffic-between-two-site-site-vpn-tunnels

[image]

You can see the info there...I won't copy/paste it all since the page on Cisco.com won't go away.

However, if after reading it you seem overwhelmed, take heart.  It's not a simple setup, and the link assumes a pretty basic network overall.  If you get stuck I'd suggest either a consultant or enlisting Cisco TAC to assist with the configuration.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your assistance! All I needed was a stepping stone to point me to the right direction. Thanks again for your tremendous help,

Comment: Welcome sir...hope you stick around here!